# How to prove that the graph of $r=\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$ is symmetric about polar axis

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I want to know how to prove that the graph of $r=\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$
is symmetric about the $x$-axis (polar axis).
As I understand it, if a polar graph is symmetrical about the $x$-axis,
$(r,\theta)$ and $(r,-\theta)$ will give the same equation.

Since $r=\sin(\frac{-\theta}{2})=-\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$, this is not the same
as $r=\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$.

Comment: In the $(r,\theta)$ coordinates, r is always taken non-negative

Comment: Which range of $\theta$ is being considered here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $\theta\mapsto-\theta$ to show it's symmetric about the $y$-axis.

And you can use $\theta\mapsto\theta+2\pi$ to show it's symmetric about the origin.

Even if you're restricting to $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ (where it's no longer symmetric about the $y$-axis) and each substitution above is individually invalid, when you put them together...

Comment: theta to -theta : will show symmetric about x-axis, not y-axis

Comment: @user138819 If $\theta\mapsto-\theta$ how does the $x$-coordinate change? How does the $y$-coordinate change? Is that a reflection across the $x$ or the $y$ axis?

Comment: There is no x-cordiante or y-coordinate in polar.

Comment: @user138819 $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, come on now. I've given you the pieces to solve this problem, but I'm not going to do the whole thing for you. You have to put the pieces together!

Comment: user138819 $\theta=0$ is still the implied reference x-axis conventionally. You are lost without any orientation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a problem where it is important to know how the polar curve is "traced out" in order to discuss questions about its polar function.  For $ \ r \ = \ \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ \ , \ $ we obtain a sort of "double cardioid" for which the "left half" is traced for the interval $ \ 0 \ < \ \theta \ < \ 2 \pi \ $ and the "right half" over $ \ 2 \pi \ < \ \theta \ < \ 4 \pi \ \ ; \ $ the curve begins at the origin for $ \ \theta \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ crosses through it at $ \ \theta \ = \ 2 \pi \ \ , \ $ and returns at $ \ \theta \ = \ 4 \pi \ \   $ to complete the cycle.

[image]

So the choice of $ \ -\theta \ $ to find the point which is the $ \ x-$axis "reflection" of the point $ \ (r \ = \ f(\theta) \ , \ \theta) \ $ will not work here.  Since the $ \ x-$intercepts of this polar curve are $ \ (1 \ , \ \pi) \ $ and $ \ (-1 \ , \ 3 \pi) \ \ $ (more about "negative radii" shortly), the point $ \ \left( \ -\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ , \ -\theta \ \right) \ $ is *not* the "vertical reflection" of $ \ \left( \ \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ , \ \theta \ \right) \ \ , \ $ but is instead at a distance $ \   +\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ $ from the origin in the direction $ \ \pi  -  \theta \ $ *exactly opposite* to $ \ -\theta \ \ , \ $ as follows from the way points at a "negative radius" from the origin are defined.  (As examples, note that $ \ (-1 \ , \ -\pi = 3 \pi) \ $ or $ \ \left( -\frac12 \ , \ -\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{5\pi}{3} \ \right) \ $ end up as "*horizontal* reflections" of  $ \ (1 \ , \ \pi ) \ $ and $ \ \left( \frac12 \ , \ \frac{\pi}{3} \ \right) \ \ , \ $ respectively.)

So how are we to show that this polar curve is symmetrical about the $ \ x-$axis?  Since the $ \ x-$axis passes through the curve at $ \ \theta \ = \ \pi \ $ and $ \ \theta \ = \ 3 \pi \ \ , \   $ the "vertically reflected" point to $ \ \pi - \theta \ $ lies at the angle  $ \pi + \theta \ $ (and similarly for the points at  $ \ 3 \pi - \theta \ $ and  $ \ 3 \pi + \theta \ \ ) \ . \ $  We can check that
$$ r \ \ = \ \ \sin \left(\frac{\pi \ - \ \theta}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ - \ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) $$
$$ = \ \ \sin \left(\frac{\pi \ + \ \theta}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ + \ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ \ ; $$

and likewise for  $ \ 3 \pi - \theta \ $ and  $ \ 3 \pi + \theta  \ \ $ (with $ \ r \ $ being equal to $ \ -\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \  \ . \ ) $