# Why are $\cos \frac{\theta}{2}$ and $-\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$ the same in the polar coordinate system?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, symmetry

I encountered this when trying to prove polar-axis symmetry for $\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$, and ended up with:

$r(\pi-\theta)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\frac\theta2\right)=\cos\frac\theta2$

Implying that $\cos \frac{\theta}{2} = -\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$, per the symmetry test $(r,\theta) \rightarrow (-r, \pi-\theta)$. I noticed that while in the rectangular system, $\cos \frac{x}{2}$ and $-\sin \frac{x}{2}$ are different, but in the polar system, they are graphically identical. Why is this so, and how do I proceed to prove the symmetry algebraically?

Comment: $\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\frac\theta2\right)=\cos\frac\theta2$ is correct, but is does not imply $\cos \frac{\theta}{2} = -\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$ (which is wrong).

Comment: But according to the symmetry test shouldn't $\cos \frac{\theta}{2}$ be equal to $-r$?

Comment: Every point on the graph of $r = -\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$ matches to a corresponding point on the graph of $r = \cos \frac{\theta}{2}$  i.e. the graphs appear to be identical.  But, $-\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \ne \cos \frac{\theta}{2}$ for any given $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

$\cos \frac{\theta}{2}$ and $-\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$ are not at all the same thing. However, when you graph $r=\cos \frac{\theta}{2}$ and $r=-\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$ you will obtain the same graph with a distinct difference that the points on the graph are traced out differently. More precise: A point of one graph "trails" a point on the other graph by $\pi$. The reason for this is that polar points of the graph do not have a unique $(r,\theta)$ representation as what you would have with Cartesian coordinates. If you have two Ti 84's and you would graph both polar curves at the same time, you can see what I mean. A very simple example to illustrate: $r=1$ and $r=-1$ both represent the unit circle, but the first one starts at $(1,0)$, and the second one at $(-1,0)$ and then they both "move" counter clockwise. Same graph, but obviously we can't say that $-1$ and $1$ are equal

Comment: So how would I go about proving the polar-axis symmetry of $\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$? Was my symmetry test correct?

Comment: Proving symmetry w.r.t. the y-axis and why two different polar formulas yield the same graph is two different things. If I want to test symmetry w.r.t. y-axis, I would replace $r$ by $-r$ and $\theta$ by $-\theta$ and see if you get the same formula back.

Comment: Graphing the two on Desmos with sliders is a great way to illustrate this.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I certainly agree, but I got 2 Ti's on my desk :) And when I change the  theta-step, I can play with the speed as well....In my class, DESMOS is the way!

Comment: I'm trying to prove x-axis symmetry, not y-axis, and I replaced $r$ with $-r$ and $\theta$ with $180-\theta$, and that's how I ended up with $\cos \frac{\theta}{2}$. My question is how does that prove that $\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$ is symmetrical? Because it clearly is symmetrical, but I fail to see how I can conclude that algebraically, if the results are not equivalent.

Thanks for the answer, btw.

Comment: This may be helpful then: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868860/how-to-prove-that-the-graph-of-r-sin-left-frac-theta2-right-is-symmetri

Comment: Thanks, but there doesn't seem to be any conclusion in that thread

Comment: The problem with symmetry tests in polars is, that even if a formula fails a symmetry test, the graph may still be symmetric. Then only making an actual graph will tell.